# Will moving my database break my project?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, server

I really could not think of a good title for this
but anyway I am building a control panel app that is basically a interface for the data in the database. (runs scripts on the database)

I have linked the database to my project using this method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171893(v=vs.140).aspx Connect to data in an Access database (Windows Forms)

So that fine however once I have built the project I am going to have to move the database to a server and then instill the control panel app on to different clients. Will moving the database break the connection with the client app? and if yes how will I be able to get the client to reconnect to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will moving the database break the connection with the client app?

Of course, it will break the database connection to your application, because you moved the database location to other device. So the application will detect that the connection is missing.

> How will I be able to get the client to reconnect to the database?

Just set the new connection string to your application. 
You can find it on your project application path.

Comment: And how would I generate this new connection string? Once ive built the client the data base will be moved to a server. I will never know what server it will be moved to or how many times it may move in the future and I cant keep rebuilding the app each time the database moves servers expsaley just because the string that points to the database changes. There needs to be a non hard coded way to do that. So A:How would some one get this string eatch time the database changes servers and B:How would I change the string in the client App. I have not seen anywhere this string is used in the code.

Comment: There are many various ways in order to achieve that. Option 1) You could create an application wherein you will choose the database connection by getting the source connection and database name including the server OR Option 2) you could just visit your client or if the client notifies you that they migrated to another server you will recreate the connection string. Option 2 is the easiest way because I know that your client will not move the database from time to time.

Comment: What do you mean visit my client? the client is not a person the client is the app(client side app) that access the database. And what I am trying to do is when the database changes server(and it will because it can not run off my computer)  How do I get the app to connect to it again with out rebuilding the App itself. Where is this string? and how do i generate it? and how do I get my app to use and update the string when it changes.

Comment: Use the server name that you can found on the SQL server database. During Authentication. For example: Server Name: SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS then get your database associated to it. You will have to create a code for this.

Answer (score 0):

the connection string to the database will be in the app.config file. you can assure that the path is relative to the exe or use another mechanism for locating the database file.

Comment: So the String that points the the client to the database is in the app.config file and so this needs to change when the database moves servers? if thats true then I just need to know how to generate the new string when the database moves.